# The reason why multi line visual selection line doesn't work

Tags: vim

I've written two simple functions as well as defined a mapping to use them. The idea is to do a `grep` type search (with `ag`) for current visual selection.

Here is the code:

```
function! s:VisualAg()
  let temp = @"
  normal! gvy
  try
    call <SID>PrjAck('"'.@".'"', g:proj_root)
  catch
    let @" = temp
    echoerr v:exception
  endtry
endfunction

function! s:PrjAck(pattern, ...)
  " -S - smart case
  " -U - ignore VCS ignore files
  " -Q - Don't parse PATTERN as a regular expression
  " -G - PATTERN Limit search to filenames matching PATTERN
  let cmd = ":Ack -S -U -Q -G \"\\.(cpp\|h\|td)$\" ".a:pattern
  for parameter in a:000
    let cmd .= " ".parameter
  endfor
  execute cmd

xnoremap <leader>gw :call <SID>VisualAg()<cr>
```

The mapping seems to work for a selection done within a line. However when I do a multi line selection it doesn't work.

Here is what I get when I run this code on a multi line selection
[image]

I tried to debug it and replaced the `execute cmd` line in `s:PrjAck(pattern, ...)` with `echo cmd`. Here is the output that I got
[image]

Frankly I'm not quite clear what is going on. I'm somewhat new to vim scripting so any help with figuring out the issue is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to manually execute the generated command in your shell?

Comment: @romainl I don't know why I didn't do it :D Stupid me, that should have been my first step. Thanks!!!

Comment: Cross posted: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/why-the-function-doesnt-work-for-multiline-visual-selelction

Comment: @SatoKatsura Not any more.

Comment: Then I'll re-add my answer here: (1) `'"'.@".'"'` doesn't do proper escaping of `"`, you need to replace it with `string(@")`. (2) This still won't work for multiple lines, because newlines in `@"` won't reach `ag`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura So how does one make `@"` reach `ag`?

Comment: Re-write `Ack.vim`. :) It's a combination of a misfeature of Vim which translates newlines to NUL characters, and a misfeature of `Ack.vim` which isn't prepared for that kind of input.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I don't follow, I think, this should work: `let pat = string(substitute(@", "\n", '\\n', 'g'))`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt And yet it doesn't.  Set `g:ackprg` to a program that prints its arguments, to find out why.  Stubborn little piece of code, isn't it.

Comment: @SatoKatsura This works for me[TM]: `:exe ':!python  -c "import sys;print(sys.argv) "'. shellescape(a:pattern,1)` and it shows all arguments.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I believe you.  But the pattern still has to survive going though `Ack.vim`.